# Custom field to update Embeddable RingCentral for Salesforce Widget userPresence

Tags: api, customsetting, cti

We are making the switch to Salesforce (from GoldMine) and we are working to implement a system that will automatically route phone calls to the appropriate trip adviser based on their destination specialization and phone availability status. This system will be looking at a custom field on a custom object we have (User Setting.user_status__c) to determine who is available.

I have been searching to try and find anything that gives me an idea of how best to accomplish this, and I feel like all the pieces are there for me to do so (the UserPresence status, accessible by the embeddable widget, maybe using Salesforce's streaming api with a connected application to subscribe to changes coming from the RC widget) but I don't know where to start in regards to having the RC embeddable send events to a custom field in Salesforce. Where would I put the code telling Salesforce to listen for User Status Presence Changes? Where do I put the code that tells the RingCentral embeddble widget to emit User Status change events?  Is the embeddable widget extensible to that degree? How does it get authorization to change a Users Salesforce Data?

It doesn't look like the event data that I want is provided by the embeddable widget based on the available events listed on [this page](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable/blob/master/docs/widget-event.md).

Comment: Have you contacted Ring Central for advice?

Comment: I have reached out to RingCentral for advice, they have a portal to request assistance on API use and I'm still waiting to hear back. I thought I'd post the question here as well in case anyone had implemented something like this before.

Comment: RingCentral Dev Platform Support got back to me with "The Coding in Salesforce is  built-in and is uneditable. What we can recommend is to consult Salesforce developer to find out if there's a way to edit the installed pckg." 

So I think I'm just going to implement a Server/no ui application and create a subscription to monitor presence changes.